# ffmpeg replace part of audio file with looped audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am quite new to ffmpeg and I am trying to replace a part of a first audio file with another second file. The second file can be too short, so some sort of loop should exist.

After some research I came up with the following command arguments and it gives me the output as long as I only do one replacement. But I would like to do multiple replacements. So any help on what I am doing wrong? Any suggestions/remarks on the way of working are also very welcome.

(Any typos in the commands below can be ignored, I generate the command by script and for ease of use I simplified the names.)

Works (One replacement):

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "first.wav" -i "second.wav" -filter_complex "[1:a][1:a][1:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceBase];[0:a]atrim=0:3,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partA];[replaceBase]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceA];[0:a]atrim=start=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partB];[partA][replaceA][partB]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[aout]" -map "[aout]" Out.wav
```

Works Not (Multiple replacements):

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "first.wav" -i "second.wav" -filter_complex "[1:a][1:a][1:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceBase];[0:a]atrim=0:3,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partA];[replaceBase]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceA];[0:a]atrim=5:4,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partB];[replaceBase]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceB];[0:a]atrim=start=6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partC];[partA][replaceA][partB][replaceB][PartC]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1[aout]" -map "[aout]" Out.wav
```

> ffmpeg version N-76860-g72eaf72 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
>     configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
>     libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
>     libavcodec     57. 16.100 / 57. 16.100
>     libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
>     libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
>     libavfilter     6. 15.100 /  6. 15.100
>     libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>     libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>     libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>   Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
>   Input #0, wav, from '3897583stereo.wav':
>     Duration: 00:00:12.07, bitrate: 256 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 256 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
>   Input #1, wav, from 'beep-021.wav':
>     Metadata:
>       encoder         : Lavf57.19.100
>     Duration: 00:00:00.30, bitrate: 1413 kb/s
>       Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
>   [wav @ 057242c0] Invalid stream specifier: replaceBase.
>       Last message repeated 1 times
>   Stream specifier '*STREAM CUT* matches no streams.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a workaround (or maybe just how it should be done) by splitting the looped stream with asplit. Remarks for the way of processing are still welcome...

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "first.wav" -i "second.wav" -filter_complex "[1:a][1:a][1:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceBase];[replaceBase]asplit=2 [replaceA][replaceB];[0:a]atrim=0:3,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partA];[replaceA]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceTrimmedA];[0:a]atrim=5:6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partB];[replaceB]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[replaceTrimmedB];[0:a]atrim=start=8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[partC];[partA][replaceTrimmedA][partB][replaceTrimmedB][PartC]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1[aout]" -map "[aout]" Out.wav
```

Regards,